# Proof expectation independent discrete random variables

Tags: proof-verification

I have a question regarding the following theorem:

> Discrete random variables $X$ and $Y$ on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb P)$ are independent if and only if
>
> $\mathbb E(g(X)h(Y))=\mathbb E(g(X))\mathbb E(h(Y))$
>
> for all functions $g,h\colon \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ for which the last two expectations exist.

The proof goes as follows:

> The necessity of the theorem follows just as in the proof of theorem //. To prove sufficiency, let $a,b\in \mathbb R$ and define $g$ and $h$ by
>
> $\begin{align}g(x)=\begin{cases}1&if\ x=a\\0&if \ x\neq a,\end{cases}
>  && g(x)=\begin{cases}1&if\ x=b\\0&if \ x\neq b,\end{cases}\end{align}$
>
> Then $\mathbb E(g(X)h(Y))=\mathbb P(X=a,Y=b)$
>
> and
>
> $\mathbb E(g(X))\mathbb E(h(Y))=\mathbb P(X=a)\mathbb P(Y=b)$
>
> giving that $p_{X,Y}(a,b)=p_X(a)p_Y(b)$.

Now, in my eyes, the proof is giving an example of the theorem instead a general proof for all functions... So, instead of working with a random functions $g$ and $h$, we work with two specific functions $g$ and $h$ and show that the theorem holds. Can someone explain to me how this is a proof for the theorem?

To be clear: I am only interested in the "sufficiency" part of the proof!

Comment: But, in "sufficiency" part of the proof, you only need to prove that $X$ and $Y$ are independent, provided that condition (1) holds for all functions $f$ and $g$. To do this, you need just indicator functions. See my answer below (I added a bit more explanation).

Comment: Please don't use proof-verification tag as the only tag on your question. Use other tags to indicate what area of mathematics the proof comes from.

Answer (score 0):

The proof says:

> The necessity of the theorem follows just as in the proof of theorem //.

So for the proof of one direction of implication, that if $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables, then $$\mathbb E(g(X)h(Y))=\mathbb E(g(X))\mathbb E(h(Y)) \tag{1}$$ for all functions $g,h: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$  for which the last two expectations exist, **they reference the proof of some other theorem**.

The rest is the proof of the other direction, that the above condition is sufficient for independence of $X$ and $Y$. To prove this, it is enough to observe the case when $g$ and $h$ are indicator functions.

Recall that discrete random variables $X$ and $Y$ will be independent iff 
$$P(X=a, Y=b)=P(X=a)P(Y=b)$$ for every $a,b \in \mathbb R$. And, indeed, if for **an abritrary** $a,b \in \mathbb R$ we put 
$$\begin{align}f(x)=\begin{cases}1,&\text{if } x=a\\0,&\text{if } x\neq a\end{cases}
 && g(x)=\begin{cases}1,&\text{if } x=b\\0,&\text{if } x\neq b\end{cases}\end{align}$$
then, from (1) we get $$P(X=a, Y=b)=E(f(X)g(Y))=E(f(X))E(g(Y))=P(X=a)P(Y=b).$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I asked my teacher as well, and I think I got it now. The sufficiency bit of the bi-implication is actually a bit strong, but if we simply assume what there is to be assumed, then we can derive that $X$ and $Y$ are independent, by simply taking a special case (it's true for all those functions $f$ and $g$).